# Kubernetes pod not starting up

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to create a kubernetes Pod on a specific node pool (in AKS, k8s v1.18.19) that has the (only) taint `for=devs:NoSchedule` and the (only) label `for: devs`. The Pod should have at least 4 cpu cores and 12gb of memory available. The node pool has size `Standard_B12ms` (so 12 vCPU and 48gb RAM) and the single node on it has version `AKSUbuntu-1804gen2-2021.07.17`. The node has status "ready".
When I start the Pod with `kubectl apply -f mypod.yaml` the pod is created but the status is stuck in `ContainerCreating`. When I reduce the resource requirements to 1 vCPU and 2gb memory it starts fine, so it seems that 4 vCPU and 12gb memory is too large but I don't get why.

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: user-ubuntu
  labels:
    for: devs
spec:
  containers:
  - name: user-ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: ["/bin/sleep", "3650d"]
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "4"
        memory: 12G
      limits:
        cpu: "6"
        memory: 20G
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/azure"
      name: volume
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
    - name: volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-user-default
  tolerations:
  - key: "for"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "devs"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
  nodeSelector:
    for: devs
```

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl describe pods  user-ubuntu`?

Comment: you need to run `kubectl get node  -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.allocatable}{"\n"}' -L for=devs` command, to check the resources available for allocation on the node where you are trying to schedule your node.

Comment: @tenticon Could you paste the output of the `kubectl describe pod user-ubuntu`, the `Events` section? Could you paste the output of the `kubectl describe node {the-node-name-that-you-mentioned}`, the `Allocatable` section?